# Set line color for fnplt in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to change the color of my curve ploted by `fnplt`. [The document here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnplt.html) makes it sound incapable of setting colors.

However, I tried `fnplt(s, 'k')`; the color of my line is indeed set to black. Then, I tried setting the line to any RGB color by `fnplt(s, [0.5 0.5 0.5])`, which doesn't work.

[The solution given here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231389-defining-rgb-color-in-curve-fitting) doesn't work either, because if you do `h = fnplt(s)`, `h` will be the points to be plotted, instead of the line handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `fnplt` does not accept the standard `Color` parameter/value pair for a line plot and also doesn't actually store any graphics handles for the plots that it creates. What you *can* do is get a list of all plot handles before and after you call `fnplt` to get the handles to the objects that were created and then manipulate their properties directly.

```
% Get a list of all graphics within the current axes
before = findall(gca);

% Plot your function
fnplt(s);

% Figure out all of the graphics that were added to the axes by fnplt
added = setdiff(findall(gca), before);

% Alter their appearance.
set(added, 'Color', [1 0 0])
```

Comment: Works like a charm. MathWorks should include this as part of their documentation! Your method gives much more than what I asked. Now I can adjust many more properties of the line. Thanks Sir!

Comment: May I ask a followup? Is it possible to set "piecewise" colors? Although `s` seems like a "whole object", I know the "keypoints" that give `s`. I want the segment of `s` between `keyPt1` and `keyPt2` to be of one color and another segment of `s`,  say,  between `keyPt4` and `keyPt5` to be of another color. This cannot be achieved by generating multiple spline curves and set colors separately, as these short curves pieced together will no longer give my original `s` that fits to all points. Thanks!

Comment: @SibbsGambling You could put the above code in a loop and provide a vector input as the second input to `fnplt` to specify the range over which to plot a function. `fnplt(s, [keyPt1, keyPt2]); fnplt(s, [keyPt2, keyPt3])`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for your very prompt and helpful comment! This again shows how general your original answer is!